# error in Angular constructor regarding JSON arrays with colDefs and rowData

Tags: arrays, angular

I have a couple of Angular constructors that are utilizing Ag Grid but getting an error, of which I'm not sure why. The app seems to work, but these errors occur on start, and won't allow me to deploy the build via npm as a result.

In one component, I get the message.

```
ERROR in src/app/carsprods/carsprods.component.ts:24:4 
- error TS2322: Type '[{ Name: string; Price: number; Category: string; },
{ Name: string; Price: number; Category: string; }, 
{ Name: string; Price: number; Category: string; },
{ Name: string; Price: number; Category: string; }, 
{ ...; }, { ...; }, { ...; }]' is not assignable to type '[]'.
  **Source has 7 element(s) but target allows only 0.**
```

My constructor looks like:

```
export class CarsprodsComponent {
private columnDefs;
private rowData: [];

  constructor() { 
                
 this.columnDefs = [
        { field: 'Name' },
        { field: 'Price' },
        { field: 'Category' }
    ];

  
   this.rowData = [
  { "Name": "Eaton BR120AF BR AFCI Circuit Breaker", "Price" : 2.50, "Category": "Power 
  Distribution / Arc Fault"},
  { .../
 "Category": "Battery / Batteries / AAA thru 9 Volt Batteries / Battery Type AAA"}
  ];
```

the rowData array in this case has seven entries, and then I get the error above in bold.
Would anyone know of a solution to this issue? Seems like it's not too difficult to solve, but I'm unsure why it's occurring. Maybe I wrongly declared something in the constructor?
Any feedback is welcomed!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your array like this **`private rowData : any[] = [];`**

Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pzxgc2?file=src/app/app.component.ts) with no such errors